# FBConnect version

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

This maybe a dumb question but I cannot find it. Where can I check which version of the FBConnect for iOS my app is currently using? I cannot find it anywhere in the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/Facebook.m)

so in your code `facebook.m` file

```
static NSString* kSDKVersion = @"2";
```

This is a SDK version

**or**

If you have downloaded folder (it looks like facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-v1.1-15-`g397c0b6`.zip)

then you can compare the [commits](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commits/master) with above marked number

Comment: The problem is that this number hasn't been changed for months and changes have been still introduced to the code so it's rather useless ;/

Comment: ha ha. Thats the facebook for you. But they have tags in their repository. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tags

So, you have to manually compare your code with tags.